# How to add Paragraph Tags in Wordpress using Visual Composer?

Tags: php, facebook

Facebook "Instant Articles" is giving me an error and asking me to do the following -

> Please include all of the text found within the body of the web
>   article. All paragraph text should be wrapped in `<p>` tags.

But, when I try to use the paragraph tags then they disappear automatically. How can I solve this error?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: How are you submitting articles to Facebook Instant Articles? Plugin or FB reads your site's RSS feed?

Comment: I tried using the plugin, but it didn't work (don't know why). Then I tried RSS and it worked. For first few minutes, my articles show as "Instant Articles" when I submit a new article, but within few hours I get the error mentioned in the question.